# Line breaks in Comment boxes

Tags: support, comments, formatting

How can I post a code block in a COMMENT box? Not just inline `code` like this, but to create something legible with a line break:

```
Like this is my code, and I want it separate
so people can read it
```

Comment: mmmm ... Perhaps in TeX?

Comment: See comment here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23722/193

Comment: I don't really find code-as-latex too readable though.

Comment: Hi, this is an old question but I was wondering if there is any updates on this? Or if it's the same. When I need a new line, I have been using the TeX 
$$ $$ 
To create new lines (doesn't work on meta), but this is not perfect.

Answer (score 6):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50446):

> Comments have no line breaks and generally no block-level formatting (such as extended blocks of code).

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757) as well.

Comment: Fun link (the bottom *this* one) - thanks. Belisarius' TeX code pasting trick does not seeem to work here in meta, but it does work in the main site, so it is possible.